# Don't show current user in <select>

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

I have a select field which shows all users in a database.

Here is my code:

```php
<select name='accountto'> 

<?php 
    mysql_select_db('cl49-xxx', $con)or die( 'Unable to select database');
    $result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM member WHERE status=2')or die('error');

    echo '<option>'; // first row beginning
    for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $businesstype= $row['businesstype'];
        $personID= $row['personID'];
        echo "<option value='$personID'>$businesstype";

        if ($i % 4 == 0) {
            echo '</option>'; // it's time no move to next row
        }
    }
    echo ''; "// last row ending
?>

</select>
```

The question is, how do I stop showing the current (logged in) user from the list?
The logged in users `personID` is stored in a cookie called `user`

Any ideas?

Comment: `if($personID === $cookiePersonId) continue;` might work?

Comment: Also, the mysql_* functions are deprecated. Look at mysqli_* or PDO instead! :)

Comment: Sounds like a vulnerability.. Be sure that personID is randomal and hard to guessing, and not appears on the rest of your site. otherwise, man can just to edit his cookie to another personID and gets access to another account. alternatively, make the cookie differ from personID, some randomal string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, Mean while, `$TotalRows = mysql_num_rows($result);` used this way instead of loop, it is executed each and every time. So I have removed `for` loop used `while` loop

```
             <?php

                $currentUser =  $_COOKIE["user"];
                mysql_select_db('cl49-xxx', $con)or die( 'Unable to select database');
                $result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM member WHERE status=2 and personID!="'.$currentUser.'" ')or die('error');
                $TotalRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                echo '<option>'; // first row beginning

                $i=1;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $businesstype= $row['businesstype'];
                    $personID= $row['personID'];

                       echo "<option value='$personID'>$businesstype";      
                        if ($i % 4 == 0) {              
                                echo '</option>'; // it's time no move to next row
                        }

                        $i++;
                }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the corresponding cookie if it contains the `personID` you're about to insert. If it does, simply don't insert it:

```
//rest of your code omitted

if($_COOKIE["user"] != $personID) {
  //insert the option
}
```

---

Another way, in order to get rid of one indendation level is to just continue the loop if the persons id equals the id stored in the cookie, so you would just add

```
if($_COOKIE["user"] == $personID) {
  continue;
}
```

after you initialized `$personID`.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand... So where would this go in my code?

Comment: @user2149630 see my edit. either you take the second approach and add this directly after `$personID = $row['personID']` or you take the first approach and paste all code after `$personID = ...` into the if-block

Answer (score 0):

in order to retrieve something from the cookie so for example logged in user

```
$loggedInUser = $_COOKIE["user"];

if ($personID != $loggedInUser)
{
    echo "<option value='$personID'>$businesstype"; 
}
```

so if the value matches the current logged in user in the cookie it wouldnt add inside the option lists

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query
`mysql_query('SELECT * FROM member WHERE status=2 and personId != $_COOKIE["user"]')or die('error');`

where personId is unique for the customer and is available in your cookie.